# Does the country of issue of an EASA medical certificate matter?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical

I am choosing the country where to do my initial for the EASA Class 1 medical. The choice is to either do it in the UK (let's ignore Brexit for now) or in Italy. In both countries I would get (if deemed fit) an EASA Class 1.

My question is: to fly and train in Europe, how important is the country of issue?
If I pass the medical, I am planning to go to an FTO in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it's probably better to do the medical in the UK as the country of issue of your licenses has to be the same as the country of issue of your medical. This way, I avoid the conversion.